# java.lang.RuntimeException: You must run the `stage` task before deploying your app when running `sbt stage deployHeroku`

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku using `sbt-nativepackager` and `sbt-heroku`.
My code is available at https://github.com/hhimanshu/sbt101/tree/m5 (branch is *m5*)

When I run `sbt stage deployHeroku`, the application fails as below

```
➜  sbt101 git:(m5) ✗ sbt stage deployHeroku
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/harit/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project sbt101-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to sbt101 (in build file:/Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/)
[info] Packaging /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/api/target/scala-2.12/api_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/api/target/scala-2.12/api_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/calculators/target/scala-2.12/calculators_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/api/target/scala-2.12/api...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/api/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
model contains 3 documentable templates
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/api/target/scala-2.12/api_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Packaging /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/api/target/scala-2.12/api_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/calculators/target/scala-2.12/api...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/calculators/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Done packaging.
[warn] there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
model contains 5 documentable templates
[warn] one warning found
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/calculators/target/scala-2.12/calculators_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[warn] there was one deprecation warning (since 2.11.0); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] two warnings found
[info] Done compiling.
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list
[info] Packaging /Users/harit/code/sc/sbt101/calculators/target/scala-2.12/calculators_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed 10-May-2019 4:20:03 PM
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: You must run the `stage` task before deploying your app!
[error]     at com.heroku.sbt.SbtApp.packageType(SbtApp.scala:142)
[error]     at com.heroku.sbt.SbtApp.prepare(SbtApp.scala:111)
[error]     at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:60)
[error]     at com.heroku.sbt.SbtApp.deploy(SbtApp.scala:98)
[error]     at com.heroku.sbt.HerokuPlugin$autoImport$.$anonfun$baseHerokuSettings$1(HerokuPlugin.scala:53)
[error]     at com.heroku.sbt.HerokuPlugin$autoImport$.$anonfun$baseHerokuSettings$1$adapted(HerokuPlugin.scala:26)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-10 16:20:03,606 Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@cb644e]-1 ERROR Attempted to append to non-started appender heroku-logger
[error] (Compile / deployHeroku) You must run the `stage` task before deploying your app!
2019-05-10 16:20:03,607 Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@cb644e]-1 ERROR Attempted to append to non-started appender heroku-logger
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 10-May-2019 4:20:03 PM
```

However, using the `Heroku toolbelt` on command-line, I have been successful in deploying my app

```
➜  sbt101 git:(m5) ✗ git push heroku m5:master
```

The the app runs at https://h2-sbt101.herokuapp.com/rates

Can someone please help me understand what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. `sbt deployHeroku` looks for the directory `target/universal/stage` (see the [source](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku/blob/0c5801106eabbb8d3a0bc8d255232fe793be252f/src/main/scala/com/heroku/sbt/SbtApp.scala#L137)). However, it seems to look for it in the root project which may not be the one with the staged directory. For example, in the OP's log, it seems there are several projects called `api` and `calculator`. In my case, the correct one (containing the server code) was `server`.

So `sbt stage server/deployHeroku` worked for me.